# Summing the total of 4 alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(case when s1 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s1_count,
    SUM(case when s2 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s2_count,
    SUM(case when s3 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s3_count,
    SUM(case when s4 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s4_count
FROM `arrest`
WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-03-01'
```

Which outputs:

```
s1_count    s2_count    s3_count    s4_count    
  17           13           6           3
```

I want to have another column called "total" which has the sum of all 4 aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't use column aliases in the `SELECT` clause, there's a couple of other ways you can do this. Either add another conditional aggregation to your query:

```
SELECT
SUM(case when s1 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s1_count,
SUM(case when s2 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s2_count,
SUM(case when s3 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s3_count,
SUM(case when s4 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s4_count,
SUM(case when s1 = 'fel' or s2 = 'fel' or s3 = 'fel' or s4 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as total
FROM `arrest`
WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-03-01'
```

Note that this assumes that only one of `s1`, `s2`, `s3` or `s4` will be equal to `fel` for any given row.

The more robust method is to use your original query as a subquery:

```
SELECT *, s1_count+s2_count+s3_count+s4_count AS total
FROM (SELECT
      SUM(case when s1 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s1_count,
      SUM(case when s2 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s2_count,
      SUM(case when s3 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s3_count,
      SUM(case when s4 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s4_count
      FROM `arrest`
      WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-03-01') a
```

Note that since MySQL treats a boolean expression in a numeric context as either 1 (true) or 0 (false) you can simplify these queries as follows:

```
SELECT
SUM(s1 = 'fel') as s1_count,
SUM(s2 = 'fel') as s2_count,
SUM(s3 = 'fel') as s3_count,
SUM(s4 = 'fel') as s4_count,
SUM((s1 = 'fel') + (s2 = 'fel') + (s3 = 'fel') + (s4 = 'fel')) as total
FROM `arrest`
WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-03-01'

SELECT *, s1_count+s2_count+s3_count+s4_count AS total
FROM (SELECT
      SUM(s1 = 'fel') as s1_count,
      SUM(s2 = 'fel') as s2_count,
      SUM(s3 = 'fel') as s3_count,
      SUM(s4 = 'fel') as s4_count
      FROM `arrest`
      WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-03-01') a
```

Doing this removes the issue the first query had of requiring that only one of `s1`, `s2`, `s3` or `s4` will be equal to `fel` for any given row.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
SELECT s1_count, s2_count, s3_count, s4_count, 
       SUM(s1_count + s2_count + s3_count + s4_count) as total_count
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        SUM(case when s1 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s1_count,
        SUM(case when s2 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s2_count,
        SUM(case when s3 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s3_count,
        SUM(case when s4 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s4_count
    FROM `arrest`
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-03-01'
) q
```

Comment: In MySQL 5.7+, MySQL 8.0+, this query will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot re-use the aliases.  The simplest way to write the code uses `in`:

```
SELECT SUM(case when s1 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s1_count,
       SUM(case when s2 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s2_count,
       SUM(case when s3 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s3_count,
       SUM(case when s4 = 'fel' then 1 else 0 end) as s4_count,
       SUM(case when 'fel' in (s1, s2, s3, s4 ) then 1 else 0 end) as total
FROM `arrest`
WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-03-01';
```

Actually, the whole query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT SUM( s1 = 'fel' ) as s1_count,
       SUM( s2 = 'fel' ) as s2_count,
       SUM( s3 = 'fel' ) as s3_count,
       SUM( s4 = 'fel' ) as s4_count,
       SUM( 'fel' in (s1, s2, s3, s4 ) ) as total
FROM `arrest`
WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2019-03-01';
```

MySQL treats boolean values as numbers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  That is handy when you want to count the number of true values of some expression.